# pSQL query against Redshift works in DataGrip but is cancelled by WLM abort action when run through R?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, rpostgresql, rjdbc

I have a query that runs within seconds through dataGrip but keeps failing when run through R; I'm at my wits end on what could be causing it. I have copied the exact string that is used for the query within R and it works just fine through dataGrip.

My connection to my Redshift database works through R- I am able to select rows and even perform simple groupby operations, so I doubt that is the issue. Here's my code/query

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(RJDBC)
library(tidyverse)
conn <- dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL"),
                  host = 'X',
                  port = 'Y',
                  user = 'A',
                  password = 'B',
                  dbname = 'C')


df = dbGetQuery(conn, str_remove_all(paste0("
SELECT 
  hour, 
  date, 
  group1, 
  group2, 
  ad_group, 
  SUM(factor1), 
  SUM(factor2), 
  SUM(factor3), 
  SUM(factor4) 
FROM table
WHERE 
  filter_col = ",value," 
GROUP BY 
  hour, 
  date, 
  group1, 
  group2, 
  group3;" 
),'\n'))
```

Error generated in console after a few seconds:

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  Query (X) cancelled by WLM abort action
DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Query (X) cancelled by WLM abort action
  code:      1078
  context:   Query (X) cancelled by WLM abort action
  query:     0
  location:  abort_query_action.cpp:Z
  process:   wlm [pid=Y]
  -----------------------------------------------

)
Warning message:
In postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) :
  Could not create execute: (above query);
```

Edit- value is a single numeric variable.

Edit2- I've just checked the timeout definitions for the Redshift cluster. It is set to 3 minutes, whereas my query was aborted in less than a minute

Comment: It is a numeric variable. Thanks for the link by the way!

Comment: I should have clarified that in the question, my apologies! `value` is a single numeric object. I just tried hardcoding a number 5, it gave me the same error within R, but when I copied the query string from R and ran it through dataGrip- it worked fine.

Comment: Then this appears to be an AWS issue ([WLM Query limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-wlm-query-monitoring-rules.html)?) Query may take a longer runtime than allowed limits. Check with your DBA regarding *timeout*.

Comment: It just seems really odd that the query works fine through dataGrip (takes less than a minute to execute), but runs into that issue when executed through R. I'll check with by DBA, but I am weary of it being an issue with it taking too long to run.

Comment: I don't use AWS or dataGrip but that's what Google turned up for me. I can tell you this error has nothing to do with SQL. Is dataGrip local to database and R makes a remote connection? Can you test query with command line like `psql`? Also, I see you import two mutually exclusive DB-APIs. You do not appear to be using `RJDBC`. If you use this over `RPostgreSQL`, update to latest RedShift JDBC driver.

Comment: I've just checked the timeout definitions for the Redshift cluster. It is set to 3 minutes, whereas my query was aborted in less than a minute.

Comment: Could be other access issues. Maybe R connection needs to have IP address whitelisted by your database. Maybe a different user than dataGrip without privileges is attempting to connect.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, my Redshift cluster has had a million row return limit; because dataGrip only shows you the first 500 rows when you run a query and actually processes ALL of it when you either download or skip to the last 'page'; I never hit this issue (until I actually tried downloading it all and dug into my Redshift cluster settings). To overcome this, I'm using offset and limit on my query in a loop to download everything I need. I hope this helps someone!